# knitr::include_graphics() doesn't generate figure label

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I've looked everywhere and I cannot figure this out.

Following the `bookdown` [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html), I used `knitr::include_graphics` to include a figure into my document that was not directly generated by R code. It shows up just fine, but I cannot use the usual `\@ref(fig:graph)` referencing. In fact, when I inspect the HTML code, the figure doesn't seem to have a label at all. My chunk looks like this:

````
```{r graph, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.cap='A logo.'}
knitr::include_graphics("data/knit-logo.png")
```
````

Does it have something to do with the styles in my header? Is there a different one I should use?

```
--- 
title: "Minimal Working Example"
author: "LilithElina"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
description: "This is a minimal working example"
---
```

(Edit for clarity.)

Comment: I opened a PR on GitHub in the bookdown book for that. This may help you understand : https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/877/files

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @Sébastien. I can put the figure caption outside of the chunk options, but I still can't reference the figure.

Comment: Your label is 'graph' not 'label'. To reference you need to use `\@ref(fig:graph)`

Comment: How do knit / build the document ?
What does your Rmd Yaml looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote this in a hurry and didn't make it clear enough. I edited the question to reflect exactly what I'm doing and added the complete YAML header. I create the document with "Preview Book".

Comment: I would use Build Book instead, but it can't deal with the `rstudioapi::askForPassword()` I use in a different section, and preview is enough for now.

Comment: Do you still have problems with that ?
If yes, did you create a new book with Rstudio IDE ? Can you try with the original example given by Rstudio, without your limitation of password to see if you can make it work.
I personally do not have the "Preview book", preview_chapter() only

Comment: Actually, I managed to solve it inspired by another post somewhere: I added `fig.align='center'` and suddenly the figure was recognised as such. Before that, I had the same problem with the regular Build Book (after I got rid of the password).